# Removing Duplicate rows based on Attribute in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

So I am a SAS user who is now using SQL for my new job.

In SAS I was able to run this query to remove duplicates:

```
proc sort data = customer_data
nodupkey out = customer_data_no_dups;
by Cus_ID;
run;
```

I want something that will give me the same result in SQL

[image]

The list is too large to do in Excel

Thanks in advance

Comment: DO you want to remove the duplicates from the main table, or from the resultset only?

Comment: Do you care WHICH of the duplicate rows for the same ID you select?  SAS will keep the first one it sees for that value of ID.

Comment: No i do not, I am fine with it just taking the first ID it sees

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result suggests me simple aggergation:

```
select CUS_ID, First, Last, min(Item) 
from table t
group by CUS_ID, First, Last;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the more accurate equivalence in older versions of MySQL is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.item = (select min(t2.item)
                from t t2
                where t2.cus_id = t.cus_id
               );
```

This lets you fetch as many column as you like from the row with the minimum item.

The one difference from your query is that you will get duplicate rows if customers can have duplicate items.

In MySQL 8+, you can use `row_number()` as well:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cus_id order by item) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have keys that are repeated, and satellite data that is not (those item #s), the row that ends up in the result set would arbitrary.  `Proc SQL` has a neat feature for automatically remerging summary statistics, and the undocumented `monotonic()` function can be used to discretize the repeated key rows (including completely identical rows), which can then be leveraged for use in a `having` clause.

This sample code creates some data with repeated keys and also some identical rows.

```
data have;
  do _n_ = 1 to 1000;
    key1 = ceil (10 * ranuni(123));
    key2 = ceil (10 * ranuni(123));
    key3 = ceil (10 * ranuni(123));
    sat1 = 100 + ceil (4 * ranuni(123));
    sat2 = 100 + ceil (4 * ranuni(123));
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql; 
  * result set for distinct rows -- some key repetition still present;
  create table distinct_all as
  select distinct * from have
  ;

  * result set for distinct keys -- fewer than distinct rows;
  create table keys as
  select distinct key1,key2,key3 from have
  ;

  * result for distinct keys with an arbitrary row amongst the repeateds;
  create table distinct_key_arb_sat(drop=seq) as
  select key1, key2, key3, sat1, sat2, monotonic() as seq
  from have
  group by key1, key2, key3
  having seq = min(seq)
  ;
```